# Replacing integers in a dataframe column that's a list of integer vectors (not just single integers) with character strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-lists

I have a dataframe with a column that's really a list of integer vectors (not just single integers).

```r
# make example dataframe
starting_dataframe <- 
  data.frame(first_names = c("Megan", 
                             "Abby", 
                             "Alyssa", 
                             "Alex", 
                             "Heather"))

starting_dataframe$player_indices <- 
  list(as.integer(1), 
       as.integer(c(2, 5)), 
       as.integer(3), 
       as.integer(4), 
       as.integer(c(6, 7)))
```

I want to replace the integers with character strings according to a second concordance dataframe.

```r
# make concordance dataframe
example_concord <- 
  data.frame(last_names = c("Rapinoe", 
                            "Wambach", 
                            "Naeher", 
                            "Morgan", 
                            "Dahlkemper", 
                            "Mitts", 
                            "O'Reilly"), 
              player_ids = as.integer(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```

The desired result would look like this:

```r
# make dataframe of desired result
desired_result <- 
  data.frame(first_names = c("Megan", 
                             "Abby", 
                             "Alyssa", 
                             "Alex", 
                             "Heather"))

desired_result$player_indices <- 
  list(c("Rapinoe"), 
       c("Wambach", "Dahlkemper"), 
       c("Naeher"), 
       c("Morgan"), 
       c("Mitts", "O'Reilly"))
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it and failed to find a similar case here on stackoverflow.  How do I do it?  I wouldn't mind a `dplyr`-specific solution in particular.

Comment: P.S. Brownie points to anyone who gets the references.  :D

Comment: Female professional USA soccer players?

Comment: Yes!  In celebration of their recent World Cup win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a "lookup dictionary" of sorts, and `lapply` across each of the ids:

```r
example_concord_idx <- setNames(as.character(example_concord$last_names),
                                example_concord$player_ids)
example_concord_idx
#            1            2            3            4            5            6 
#    "Rapinoe"    "Wambach"     "Naeher"     "Morgan" "Dahlkemper"      "Mitts" 
#            7 
#   "O'Reilly" 

starting_dataframe$result <- 
  lapply(starting_dataframe$player_indices,
         function(a) example_concord_idx[a])
starting_dataframe
#   first_names player_indices              result
# 1       Megan              1             Rapinoe
# 2        Abby           2, 5 Wambach, Dahlkemper
# 3      Alyssa              3              Naeher
# 4        Alex              4              Morgan
# 5     Heather           6, 7     Mitts, O'Reilly
```

(Code golf?)

```r
Map(`[`, list(example_concord_idx), starting_dataframe$player_indices)
```

Comment: @rilkehayden - making code as short as possible while still being functional - see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

For `tidyverse` enthusiasts, I adapted the second half of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024667/7420578) by [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) to use `map()` and `%>%`:

```r
require(tidyverse)

starting_dataframe <- 
  starting_dataframe %>% 
  mutate(
    result = map(.x = player_indices, .f = function(a) example_concord_idx[a])
  )
```

Definitely won't win code golf, though!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to `unlist` the list-column, and `relist` it after modifying its contents:

```r
df1$player_indices <- relist(df2$last_names[unlist(df1$player_indices)], df1$player_indices)
df1
#>   first_names      player_indices
#> 1       Megan             Rapinoe
#> 2        Abby Wambach, Dahlkemper
#> 3      Alyssa              Naeher
#> 4        Alex              Morgan
#> 5     Heather     Mitts, O'Reilly
```

**Data**

```r
## initial data.frame w/ list-column
df1 <- data.frame(first_names = c("Megan", "Abby", "Alyssa", "Alex", "Heather"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$player_indices <- list(1, c(2,5), 3, 4, c(6,7))

## lookup data.frame
df2 <- data.frame(last_names = c("Rapinoe", "Wambach", "Naeher", "Morgan", "Dahlkemper", 
        "Mitts", "O'Reilly"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

NB: I set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to create character columns in the data.frames, but it works just as well with factor columns instead.